# PostgreSQL 9.2 streaming replication recovery.conf

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am working on Postgresql 9.2 streaming replication and I have finished setting up on the master and on the standby I want to set up the parameters in `recovery.conf` file.

But I can not get the file so I have created a new file 'named recovery.conf' and copied all the contents of `recovery.conf.sample` file and edited the parameters.

I saved  it and when I start the postgresql service, it gives error

> "service on local computer started and stopped....."

But when I remove `recovery.conf` file the service starts.

I need help.

Comment: Thanks for including the version. You need to take a look at the PostgreSQL log files in your PostgreSQL install directory, under `data\pg_log`, to see if they contain anything relevant. Please also show the exact `recovery.conf` you have used.

Comment: EAT LOG:  entering standby mode
EAT WARNING:  WAL was generated with wal_level=minimal, data may be missing
EAT HINT:  This happens if you temporarily set wal_level=minimal without taking a new base backup.
EAT FATAL:  hot standby is not possible because wal_level was not set to "hot_standby" on the master server
EAT HINT:  Either set wal_level to "hot_standby" on the master, or turn off hot_standby here.
EAT LOG:  startup process (PID 3756) exited with exit code 1
EAT LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure

Comment: Well, the log tells you what's wrong and what to do about it.

Comment: Ofcourse! I checked for all the configuration setup if i made a mistake but it is all set correct.